# $C^1$ harmonic functions on a dense open set are globally harmonic

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-functions

In a paper I am studying, at a certain point the authors introduce a function $u\in C^1(B_1,\mathbb{R})$ which is harmonic in a dense open subset $U$ of $B_1$. From this, they seem to conclude that $u$ must be harmonic in all $B_1$. Is this fact true? Any hint on how to prove it? It should be elementary but I keep getting stuck. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think the claim is true.

Let $\mathfrak{C}$ be the ternary Cantor set in $[0,1]$; note that it is closed and nowhere dense, so its complement is open and dense.
Let $C:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function). It is continuous, and is differentiable on $(0,1)\setminus \mathfrak{C}$, where its derivative is $0$.

As $C$ is continuous, it is Riemann integrable, and the fundamental theorem of calculus applies: in particular, there exists some function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f\in C^1$ and $f' = C$.

This function $f$ is a $C^1$ function on $(0,1)$, which has a continuous (in fact vanishing) second derivative on an open, dense subset. Yet $f$ is not harmonic.

---

For higher dimensions, just let $g:B_1\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $g(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = f(x_1)$.

---

There are some theorems concerning removable singularities for harmonic functions, but usually these require some amount of "isolation" of the singular points. For example:

- <strike>If you know that $u\in C^1(B_1, \mathbb{R})$ and $u$ is harmonic on $B_1 \setminus \{x_1 = 0\}$, then $u$ must be harmonic on the whole ball by unique continuation.</strike> (The previous argument is only true if you make certain existence assumptions. So let's cross that out for now.) (The result however is true [using a different argument]; see Giorgio's comment below.)
- If you know that $u$ is harmonic on $B_1\setminus \{0\}$ and that $u$ does not blow-up too fast at $0$ (compared to the Newton potential), then $u$ has a harmonic extension to the whole of $B_1$. This is a standard removable continuity result.

Maybe in the paper you are studying there are additional properties of $u$ that is used beyond what you stated in the question?

Comment: How do you use the unique continuation property in the first case?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: I had an argument in my head which got around the potential lack of existence using Cauchy-Kovalevskaya, but your comment reminded me that the trace of $u$ on $\{x_1 = 0\}$ need not be real analytic; so let me cross that out.

Comment: However seems to be true. We write Green's identitty for $u\Delta \phi-\phi \Delta u$ in the upper and lower ball (first with $|x_1| \geq \epsilon$ and then let $\epsilon \to 0$) and add. The boundary terms cancel and we get that $\int_B u \Delta \phi=0$, so that $u$ is harmonic in the distributional sence and apply Weyl's lemma.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: on $B_1 \cap [((0,1)\setminus\mathfrak{C})\times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}]$. It is harmonic on that set as $\partial^2_{ii} g = 0$ for every $i\in \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: thanks! That's a better argument.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: thinking about your argument a bit more, it seems to be basically an argument based on the capacity of the "singular set", which makes sense as the counterexample I gave has $\mathfrak{C}$ having positive Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: Yes true even though in this case there is an heuristic explanation. If $u$ is harmonic up and below the plane $y=0$ and $C^1$ everywhere, the tangential derivatives on the plane coincide from above and below and the same holds for the mixed derivatives since $u_y$ is continuos too. The only missing derivative is $u_{yy}$ which we recover from the equation. This argument however needs more regularity or some adjustement while Weyl's lemma applies immediately.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: $u(x,y)=x$ is a non-constant harmonic function that depends on one variable only. (This is also essentially the function Willie constructs above.)

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: As I understand it, Willie's function is $u(x,y)=m_jx+c_j$ on $a_j<x<b_j$, with the parameters adjusted such that $u\in C^1(\mathbb R^2)$ and $A=\bigcup (a_j,b_j)\times \mathbb R$ is dense and open. This function is harmonic on $A$ (but of course not on $\mathbb R^2$).

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: I completely fail to understand your objection. I constructed a function that is harmonic on an open dense set (on each connected component of the open dense set it is in fact linear, and hence is harmonic). This function does not have all second partials outside of this dense set (it does not have $\partial^2_{x^1 x^1}$).

Comment: My answer is based on the following simple observations: given a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and a function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ with $g(x,y) = f(x)$. (a) If $f$ is harmonic on an open set $U$, then $g$ is harmonic on $U\times \mathbb{R}$. (b) If $U$ is open and dense in $\mathbb{R}$, then $U\times \mathbb{R}$ is open and dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Which of the two steps do you object to?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example.

When $n=2$, let $E$ be a closed nowhere dense set of positive Lebesgue measure. Then it is easy to see that the function
$$u(z)=\int_E\log|z-\zeta|d\zeta$$
is $C^1$. (Here $z$ and $\zeta$ are complex numbers.) Indeed, its convolution with an infinitely smooth
kernel $k_t\to\delta$ is infinitely smooth, and as $t\to 0$,
the convergence of the first derivatives is uniform.

When $n>2$, make the function independent of all but two variables.